# how to find all elements having a specific attribute using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out how to find all elements that have a specific attribute.  I haven't been able to figure it out without knowing the element beforehand.  This is using plain vanilla javascript.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular *[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* Do your research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and an [attribute matching selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Attribute_selectors):

`document.querySelectorAll('[myattribute]')`

That should do the trick for you.

An example:

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('[myattr]'));
```

```html
<div>
  <p myattr="test">hello</p>
  <ul>
    <li myattr="somethingelse">world</li>
    <li>!!!</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Open the console and you'll see the `<p>` and `<li>` that have class `myattr` are returned.

Comment: I already tried that, and it doesn't work.  I can't use the predefined attributes like id or class.  I need to use a custom attribute.

Comment: I have just tested it and seen it work.  Let me add a snippet to show you.

Comment: @WilliamS - please see the included snippet as a proof-of-concept.  If this is not working for you, I believe there must be something else going on in your code.  Please review [ask] and consider editing this question.  Remember, well-formed, high-quality questions are important for getting useful feedback from the community.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: Actually, your answer is correct.  It did work.  I had a typo.  Thanks for verifying.  I'll upvote your answer once I get enough points!

Comment: @WilliamS - glad to hear you were able to resolve your issue!  Although you may not have a sufficient score to vote on answers yet, you _should_ be able to mark one answer submitted to your own question as correct, which provides points for the answer-er and also indicates to users coming to this post later which answer best solved the posted question.  Thanks!